# Errors when calling games.players.get from Unity Google Play Games Services plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-developers-console

We're working on a game using Unity and we're having some problems on Android when using the Google Play Services plugin and GPGS. The app is live and I'm trying to fix a problem we're seeing in the developer console.

So when checking Metrics under console.developers.google.com we're seeing that `games.players.get` has 96.59% errors. When checking the "Traffic by response code" graph the second-most received response is 402 (the first being 200).

I've looked over the response codes and 402 seems to be called when quotas are set too low. I've checked our quotas and they're far higher than anything our app reaches per second or monthly.

We're not seeing this error during testing and I'm not exactly sure how to debug this issue. Does anyone know anything more about these kinds of issues? Is there something more I could learn from the development console that could help us out? Any help would be greatly appreciated.